# Correlation in Windows Workflow

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4, correlation, workflowservice

I am new to WF and i am working on the correlation on WF.i am not finding any step by step guide which explains correlation in easy language. please suggest me some step by step and easy to implement thing.kindly anyone have useful links

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout th following link. You may need to read part 1 first

http://blog.petegoo.com/index.php/2010/06/26/wf4-services-part-2-ndash-correlation/